# Reorder the output of a javascript function

Tags: javascript, calendar

Here is my code. It currently creates this: [image] 
but I need it to display the days of the week below the dates. I know its probably just a matter of switching 2 lines around but my javascript skills are limited and i'm struggling. any help greatly appreciated.

```
   var Timeline = function (container, date) {
        this.daysPerMonth = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
        this.weekDays = ["sunday", "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday"];
        this.monthsOfYear = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
        this.dayNumbers = {
            "sunday": 0,
            "monday": 1,
            "tuesday": 2,
            "wednesday": 3,
            "thursday": 4,
            "friday": 5,
            "saturday": 6
        };
        this.initialize = function () {
            this.isIE6 = (jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version == "6.0");
            this.container = $("#" + container);
            if (!this.container.length) {
                alert("can not locate container element \"" + container + "\"!");
                return;
            }
            this.bubble = new Timeline.Bubble(this);
            this.date = (date) ? date : new Date();
            this.readEvents();
            this.placeHolders = this.setupPlaceHolders();
            this.container.addClass("timeline");
            this.render();
        },
        this.readEvents = function () {
            this.events = [];
            var eventList = this.container.find("ul");
            var eventItems = eventList.find("li");
            for (var i = 0; i < eventItems.length; i++) {
                var date = new Date(eventItems[i].getAttribute("title"));
                if (date == "Invalid Date") continue;
                this.events[i] = {
                    name: eventItems[i].className,
                    date: date,
                    day: date.getDate(),
                    month: date.getMonth(),
                    year: date.getFullYear(),
                    content: jQuery(eventItems[i]).html()
                };
            }
            var j, tmp, events = this.events;
            for (var i = 1; i < events.length; i++) {
                tmp = this.events[i];
                for (j = i; j > 0 && events[j - 1].date > tmp.date; j--)
                events[j] = events[j - 1];
                events[j] = tmp;
            }
            eventList.remove();
        }
        this.render = function () {
            this.placeHolders.arrows.empty();
            this.placeHolders.top.empty();
            this.placeHolders.bottom.empty();
            var monthRepresentation = this.getMonthRepresentation();
            for (var i = 0; i < monthRepresentation.length; i++)
            this.renderDay(this.placeHolders.top, this.placeHolders.bottom, monthRepresentation[i]);
            if (this.isIE6) this.handleIE6Issues();
            this.setupArrows();
        }
        this.handleIE6Issues = function () {
            var clone = this.placeHolders.top.clone(true);
            this.container.append(clone);
            clone.css({
                left: "-1000px",
                top: "-1000px"
            });
            var width = clone.outerWidth();
            clone.remove();
            this.placeHolders.top.css({
                width: width + "px"
            });
            this.placeHolders.bottom.css({
                width: width + "px"
            });
        }
        this.renderDay = function (topRow, bottomRow, data) {
            var cssClass = "";
            cssClass += (this.isToday(data.number)) ? "today" : "";
            cssClass += (data.events.length) ? " event" : "";
            topRow.append("<li class=\"" + data.name  + "\"><div class=\"" + cssClass + "\">" + data.name + "</div></li>");
            bottomRow.append("<li class=\"" + data.name  + "\"><div class=\"" + cssClass + "\">" + data.number + "</div></li>");
            nameEl = topRow.find("div:last");
            numbEl = bottomRow.find("div:last");
            if (data.events.length == 0) return;
            var self = this;
            var enterClosure = function (e) {
                self.onMouseEnter(e);
            };
            var leaveClosure = function (e) {
                self.onMouseLeave(e);
            };
            nameEl.bind("mouseenter", data, enterClosure);
            numbEl.bind("mouseenter", data, enterClosure);
            nameEl.bind("mouseleave", data, leaveClosure);
            numbEl.bind("mouseleave", data, leaveClosure);
        }
        this.setupArrows = function () {
            var dateString = this.monthsOfYear[this.date.getMonth()] + " " + this.date.getFullYear();
            var html = "";
            html += "<div class=\"timeline_lastyear\" title=\"Previous Year\"></div>"
            html += "<div class=\"timeline_lastmonth\" title=\"Previous Month\"></div>"
            html += "<div class=\"timeline_date\">" + dateString + "</div>"
            html += "<div class=\"timeline_nextmonth\" title=\"Next Month\"></div>"
            html += "<div class=\"timeline_nextyear\" title=\"Next Year\"></div>"
            this.placeHolders.arrows.append(html);
            var children = this.placeHolders.arrows.children();
            var self = this;
            $(children[0]).bind("click", this, function () {
                self.previousYear()
            });
            $(children[1]).bind("click", this, function () {
                self.previousMonth()
            });
            $(children[3]).bind("click", this, function () {
                self.nextMonth()
            });
            $(children[4]).bind("click", this, function () {
                self.nextYear()
            });
        }
        this.getEventsForDay = function (dayNumber) {
            var result = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < this.events.length; i++) {
                var e = this.events[i];
                if (e.day == dayNumber && e.month == this.date.getMonth() && e.year == this.date.getFullYear()) result.push(this.events[i]);
            }
            return result;
        }
        this.setupPlaceHolders = function () {
            var arrows = jQuery(document.createElement("div"));
            arrows.addClass("timeline_arrows");

            var bottom = jQuery(document.createElement("div"));
            bottom.addClass("timeline_bottom");
            var top = jQuery(document.createElement("div"));
            top.addClass("timeline_top");
            top.append("<ul></ul>");
            bottom.append("<ul></ul>");
            this.container.append([arrows[0], top[0], bottom[0]]);
            return {
                arrows: arrows,

                bottom: bottom.find("ul:first"),
                top: top.find("ul:first")
            };
        }
        this.getMonthRepresentation = function () {
            var result = [];
            var numberOfDays = this.getNumberOfDaysInMonth(this.date);
            var firstDay = this.getFirstDayOfMonth(this.date);
            var finished = false;
            for (var i = 0; i < numberOfDays; i++) {
                result.push({
                    name: this.weekDays[firstDay].substring(0, 3),
                    number: (i + 1 < 10) ? "0" + (i + 1) : (i + 1),
                    events: this.getEventsForDay(i + 1)
                });
                firstDay = (firstDay == 6) ? 0 : ++firstDay;
            }
            return result;
        }
        this.getNumberOfDaysInMonth = function (dateObject) {
            var month = dateObject.getMonth();
            if (month == 1) {
                var leapYear = (new Date(dateObject.getYear(), 1, 29).getDate()) == 29;
                if (leapYear) return 29
                else return 28;
            } else return this.daysPerMonth[month];
        },
        this.getFirstDayOfMonth = function (dateObject) {
            var save = dateObject.getDate();
            dateObject.setDate(1);
            var result = dateObject.getDay();
            dateObject.setDate(save);
            return result;
        },
        this.isToday = function (dayNumber) {
            var today = new Date();
            return (today.getDate() == dayNumber && today.getFullYear() == this.date.getFullYear() && today.getMonth() == this.date.getMonth());
        },
        this.onMouseEnter = function (event) {
            var left = $(event.target).offset().left;
            var width = $(event.target).outerWidth();
            this.bubble.setContent(event.data.events);
            this.bubble.show(left + (width / 2));
        }
        this.onMouseLeave = function (event) {
            this.bubble.hide();
        }
        this.nextMonth = function () {
            this.date.setMonth(this.date.getMonth() + 1);
            this.render();
        }
        this.nextYear = function () {
            this.date.setYear(this.date.getFullYear() + 1);
            this.render();
        }
        this.previousMonth = function () {
            this.date.setMonth(this.date.getMonth() - 1);
            this.render();
        }
        this.previousYear = function () {
            this.date.setYear(this.date.getFullYear() - 1);
            this.render();
        }
        this.initialize();
    }
    Timeline.Bubble = function (timeline) {
        this.initialize = function () {
            var IE6Class = (timeline.isIE6) ? " bubbleIE6" : "";
            var id = "bubble_" + new Date().getTime();
            var html = "";
            html += "<div id=\"" + id + "\" class=\"timeline_bubble\">";
            html += "<div class=\"bubble_top" + IE6Class + "\"></div>";
            html += "<div class=\"bubble_mid" + IE6Class + "\"></div>";
            html += "<div class=\"bubble_bottom" + IE6Class + "\"></div></div>";
            timeline.container.after(html);
            this.container = $("#" + id);
            this.container.bind("mouseenter", this, this.onMouseEnter);
            this.container.bind("mouseleave", this, this.onMouseLeave);
        }
        this.onMouseEnter = function (event) {
            event.data.stopHiding();
        }
        this.onMouseLeave = function (event) {
            event.data.hide();
        }
        this.stopHiding = function () {
            if (this.goingOffHandle && this.goingOffHandle != null) {
                clearTimeout(this.goingOffHandle);
                this.goingOffHandle = null;
            }
        }
        this.setContent = function (events) {
            this.stopHiding();
            var html = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++)
            html += "<div><div class=\"event_title\">" + events[i].name + "<p class=\"event_data\">" + events[i].content + "</p></div></div>";
            var midSection = $(this.container.children()[1]);
            midSection.empty();
            midSection.append(html);
            var titles = midSection.find(".event_title");
            titles.each(function (inx, element) {
                $(element).bind("mouseenter", function (event) {
                    $(element).children(":first").animate({
                        opacity: "toggle"
                    }, 200);
                });
                $(element).bind("mouseleave", function (event) {
                    $(element).children(":first").animate({
                        opacity: "hide"
                    }, 200);
                });
            });
        }
        this.show = function (at) {
            this.container.animate({
                opacity: "show"
            }, 250);
            this.container.animate({
                left: at - (this.container.outerWidth() / 2)
            }, 300);
        }
        this.hide = function () {
            var self = this;
            this.goingOffHandle = setTimeout(function () {
                self.container.animate({
                    opacity: "hide"
                }, 250);
            }, 700);
        }
        this.initialize();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In `this.renderDay` try inverting the two `.append` lines :

```
topRow.append("<li class=\"" + data.name  + "\"><div class=\"" + cssClass + "\">" + data.name + "</div></li>");
bottomRow.append("<li class=\"" + data.name  + "\"><div class=\"" + cssClass + "\">" + data.number + "</div></li>");
```

so that it reads

```
bottomRow.append("<li class=\"" + data.name  + "\"><div class=\"" + cssClass + "\">" + data.number + "</div></li>");
topRow.append("<li class=\"" + data.name  + "\"><div class=\"" + cssClass + "\">" + data.name + "</div></li>");
```